# HCL Domino AppDevPack - Problem with write attachments other than .txt

Tags: file-upload, lotus-domino, hcl, domino-appdev-pack

I use this code (suppose the connection to the database has already been made) :

```
const fs = require('fs');

let docUnid = "F09C0DB42276F208C1258513005722D1";
let sFilename = fileSamplePdf.pdf; // !!! Does not work for reading after attachment !!!
// let sFilename = fileSampleTxt.txt; !!! Work for reading after attachment !!!

let buffer = fs.readFileSync("/tmp/" + sFilename);
const writable = await database.bulkCreateAttachmentStream({});
writable.on('error', e => {
  console.error("Error on write File", e);
});
writable.on('response', response => {
  console.log("File " + sFilename + " saved to doc " + docUnid);
});
let offset = 0;
const writeRemaining = () => {
  if (error) {
    return;
  }
  let draining = true;
  while (offset < buffer.length && draining) {
    const remainingBytes = buffer.length - offset;
    let chunkSize = 16 * 1024;
    if (remainingBytes < chunkSize) {
      chunkSize = remainingBytes;
    }
    const chunk = new Uint8Array(
      buffer.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize),
    );
    draining = writable.write(chunk);
    //draining = writable.write(buffer.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize)); !!! Does not work, generate a GrpcError !!!
    offset += chunkSize;
  }
  if (offset < buffer.length) {
    writable.once('drain', writeRemaining);
  } else {
    writable.end();
  }
};
writable.file({
  unid: docUnid,
  fileName: sFilename,
});
writeRemaining();
```

It works perfectly whatever the size of the file (since version 1.0.3), and the file is attached to the document in the "$File" field (size file is correct) :

```
Field Name: $FILE
Data Type: Attached Object
Data Length: 57 bytes
Seq Num: 100
Dup Item ID: 0
Field Flags: ATTACH SIGN SEAL SUMMARY 

Object Type: File
Object ID: 00000266
Object Length: 486481
File Name: fileSamplePdf.pdf
Flags: 
Host: UNKNOWN
Compression Type: NONE 
Encoding Type: 
File Attributes: RW PUBLIC 
File Size: 486481
File Created: 15/04/2020 16:56:08
File Modified: 15/04/2020 16:56:08
```

But after the attachment, if the type of attached file is **other than txt** (ex: jpg, pdf, ...), **it cannot then be read**, even from the Notes client, this generates a read error.

I compared the properties of the $File field of one file of type txt and another and there are no differences other than the properties of the file.

I'm using a Windows system with IBM Domino (r) Server (64 Bit), Release 10.0.1FP3 and AppDevPack 1.0.3.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: So you're saying you do one call to write an attachment with a stream... if you do another call to write an attachment with another stream, no matter what the file is, it can't be read?

Comment: No, if the attached file is of type txt, it can be read, otherwise, it cannot, and there is only one attached file at a time

Comment: our internal tests are doing exactly what you describe with images  write and read and verify round-trip data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you be able to share some code?  And maybe upgrade to FP4 and use the latest release (1.0.4)?

One issue you may have if you haven't upgraded your domino-db client correctly is the use of Buffers vs U8Int arrays.
In 1.0.3, I put in support to use buffers to avoid the issue on write, but there's a second param on read to grab the buffer.

Comment: I add the code in my post, it's very basic.
I'm going to try version 1.0.4, but I don't really believe it because it should already work in 1.0.3 ...

Comment: This issue looks very familiar to something we've fixed.  Windows server running proton and uploading binary attachments like images.  There was some weird code that microsoft had that was interpreting newlines and changing them to \r\n.  I'm pretty sure we fixed that in 1.0.3, but please check that 1.0.4 is working and that the domino-db node module is up to date (delete the old one in node_modules) and that the proton binary on the server has been correctly replaced.

Comment: I have upgraded Domino realease to 10.0.1FP4, Proton (sources: 1001-proton-addin-0.6.1.zip) and NodeJs domino-db module (sources: domino-domino-db-1.5.18.tgz) to 1.0.4.

Then, i have tested exactly the same code and it works properly, all file types (jpg, pdf, ...) can be read after attachment.

Thank you for you help !

Comment: I have upgraded Domino realease to 10.0.1FP4, Proton (sources: 1001-proton-addin-0.6.1.zip) and NodeJs domino-db module (sources: domino-domino-db-1.5.18.tgz) to 1.0.4.

Then, i have tested exactly the same code and it works properly, all file types (jpg, pdf, ...) can be read after attachment.

I add that the line "draining = writable.write(buffer.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize))" that caused an GrpcError on 1.0.3 now works, so it is no longer useful to go through "Uint8Array"

Thank you for you help !